# Can anyone point out where the problem is?, just working through JWT and the server is just hanging with no information being sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

**server.js file**

creating the array and posting username and title

```
const posts = [
  {
    username: "liam",
    title: "Post 1",
  },
  {
    username: "phil",
    title: "Post 2",
  },
];
```

Routes and requests have been created below

```
app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
  res.json(posts);
});
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  // auth
  const username = req.body.username;
  const user = { name: username };

  const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
  res.json({ accessToken: accessToken });
});

app.listen(5000);
```

**.rest file for requests **

get and post requests to server

```
GET http://localhost:5000/posts


###

POST http://localhost:5000/login
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "username": "liam"
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If not maybe you should check error-handling, in case you are suppressing errors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

ok, try like this ,

> > index.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
    const express = require('express');
    const app =  express();
    
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
    
    app.use(express.json());
    
    
    const posts = [
        {
          username: "liam",
          title: "Post 1",
        },
        {
          username: "phil",
          title: "Post 2",
        },
      ];
    
    
      app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
        res.json(posts);
      });
      app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
        // auth
        const username = req.body.username;
        const user = { name: username };
      
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESSTOKEN_SECRET_KEY );
        res.json({ accessToken: accessToken });
      });
      
      app.listen(5000);
```

> > .env
> > u can use  **ACCESSTOKEN_SECRET_KEY** like this

```
ACCESSTOKEN_SECRET_KEY  = a05d60271cc7e98e191c88b2b54e85f1a5ef50d35e6ef534331f0f2eec3489d7f37ba7eed8062c525781d856360c86d0ad49c539837909998134f958f0d428d0
```

//this is only an example u can use other values also no problem with that this is for secure the data/user/routes

> > > sample.rest

post http://localhost:5000/login
Content-Type: application/json

{
"username":"liam"
}

If you use it like this you will definitely **ACCESSTOKEN**
I think the problem, is maybe you are not loading .env variables,
secret private key must have a value